# Hiding a MenuItem button and showing a ProgressBar in an ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-activity, menuitem, android-progressbar

I have an activity that contains fragments. There is a refresh button in the action bar, that when pressed, I want to convert to a progress bar to show activity. Though I am getting the following error:

> Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp.Views.MasterDetails.MasterActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'android.view.MenuItem
>   android.view.MenuItem.setActionView(android.view.View)' on a null
>   object reference

On this line: `itemBtnRefresh.setActionView(abprogress);` as soon as the background action starts ("refreshData()")

Any help on properly swapping a button for an indeterminate progressbar?

```
public class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ActionBar ab;
    private MenuItem itemBtnRefresh;
    private View abprogress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_master);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.masterToolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        abprogress = inflater.inflate(R.layout.refresh_menuitem, null);

        refreshData();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_master, menu);
        itemBtnRefresh = menu.findItem(R.id.master_refresh_action);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.master_refresh_action:
                refreshData();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void refreshData() {

        //... do a background task
        // show the progressbar and hide the refresh button

        itemBtnRefresh.setActionView(abprogress);


        //.. finish the background task
        // hide progressbar and show button
        itemBtnRefresh.setActionView(null);
    }

}
```

**menu_master.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/master_refresh_action"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh"
        android:title="Refresh"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

**refresh_menuitem.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:paddingLeft="4dp"
              android:paddingRight="4dp"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              style="?attr/actionButtonStyle">
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Small"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` is executing after `onCreate` and your first `refreshData()` call, so ´itemBtnRefresh´ is still null.

Try calling it just after `itemBtnRefresh` is initialized in `onCreateOptionsMenu`.